# FOXCHKSUM algorithm

Tags: foxpro

Who knows how this function calculates checksum values?

My goal is to rewrite the FoxPro application on .NET, preserving the old database, but some values in the DB were calculated with this function.

---

**Question is closed.**

I didn't notice that FOXCHKSUM has been internal function in the project.

--

But, anyway, thanx for aswers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is it interested to somebody - I found Foxpro algorithm that calc Crc16 and Crc32 with functions **SYS(2107)** and **SYS(2007)**. (See answer of @Stuart DunkeId).

It is not really CRC, but some checksum calculation. Anyway that function return just the same result that foxpro analog.

Here is it on C#:

```
    public static uint Crc(byte[] bytes, uint seed = (uint)0, int lcBitLen = 16)
    {
        var laPower = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
        var lnBitLen = lcBitLen == 32 ? 0x8005 : 0x1021; // 1021 hex (16bit), 8005 hex (32bit)
        var lnCrc = seed == 0 ? 0xffffffff : seed;       // Reset for Each Text Block
        foreach (var byteVal in bytes)
        {
            for (var inLoop = 7; inLoop >= 0; inLoop--)
            {
                var testBit = ((lnCrc & 0x8000) == 0x8000 && (byteVal & laPower[inLoop]) != laPower[inLoop])
                              || ((lnCrc & 0x8000) != 0x8000 && (byteVal & laPower[inLoop]) == laPower[inLoop]);
                lnCrc = (lnCrc & 0x7fff)*2;
                if (testBit)
                    lnCrc = (uint)(lnCrc ^ lnBitLen);
            }
        }
        return lnCrc;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The FoxPro checksum functions [SYS(2107)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/209y8kd6%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [SYS(2007)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csfkkhcy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) use [CRC16 or CRC32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) to calculate the checksum values. Is it possible that the FOXCHKSUM function is wrapping these?

Answer (score 0):

In Foxpro You could make a class with a method wich utilizes the FOXCHKSUM function.
Then compile it into COM dll and then use it in your .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

From the obvious sounds of it, its trying to calculate some check-sum value... maybe record level, or specific field content.  I would look in the original VFP code to see what is being passed to the function call to get the results back.  Then, I would look into the .Net libraries that also deal with encryption / checksums such as MD5 as a simple one.  Then, you can try calling a standard .net function with the same string until you find out which one gives you the same results, then you don't have to deal with COM.  I don't even know if FoxChkSum is a VFP coded function or an external .fll or .dll.  If its VFP code, I can probably help out decyphering it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Testing slightly updated algorithm in Visual FoxPro (I am lazy to install C#): The CRC16 works well but CRC32 gives different results...

```
aa = 'bbb'
? aa
? SYS(2007,aa,0,0)
? sys2007(aa,0)

FUNCTION sys2007
LPARAMETERS lcString, lnBitFlag

LOCAL lnBitLen, lnCRC, inLoop, n
lnBitLen = IIF(BITTEST(m.lnBitFlag,0), 0x8005, 0x1021)

lnCRC = 0xffffffff

FOR n = 1 TO LEN(m.lcString)
  byteVal = ASC(SUBSTR(m.lcString, m.n, 1))
  FOR inLoop = 7 TO 0 STEP -1
    testbit = BITTEST(m.lnCRC, 15) AND !BITTEST(byteVal, inLoop) OR ;
              !BITTEST(m.lnCRC, 15) AND BITTEST(byteVal, inLoop)
    lnCRC = BITLSHIFT(BITAND(m.lnCRC, 0x7fff), 1)
    IF testbit
      lnCRC = BITXOR(m.lnCRC, m.lnBitLen)
    ENDIF
  NEXT
NEXT

RETURN m.lnCRc
```